# Most efficient way to check if a session is still valid/handle connectionError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests, python-3.5

How can I check if a Session in Python 3.5 will still be able to handle `get()` requests? Is there a standard procedure that people use to check for this when sending `get()` requests with a Session when they reuse the same Session for multiple requests?

Specifically, I'd like to handle `ConnectionErrors` as efficiently as possible; I have to write code that's *supposed* to be as high-performance as possible.

Example of an error I'd like to avoid or manage as efficiently as possible:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rauth\session.py", line 210, in request
    return super(OAuth1Session, self).request(method, url, **req_kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 426, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to catch the exceptions raised by `requests` and handle them gracefully (see [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions)), use [timeout values](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts) and possibly use a retry strategy that fits to your use case, and do unit testing with mocking [responses](https://pypi.org/project/responses/). Not sure what else you mean with *manage efficiently*.